# Any good documentation on ASP.NET MVC3 action methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, attributes

I have been trying to find out about ASP.NET MVC action methods or whatever the proper reference is for these:

```
[TestClass]
public class HomeControllerTest
{

[TestMethod]
public void About()
{
```

I have seen a lot of them and wondered if there is a list or reference somewhere?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Those look like unit tests to me.  It's part of some testing framework like NUnit.

Comment: Im just trying to find reference in general for method attributes and how I can specify them.

Comment: You mean how to create attributes to decorate functions/classes?

Comment: Yes exactly and the current list of them available and what they do.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the most basic form of [creating an attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sw480ze8%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).  [Here](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/ASP-NET-MVC-2-0-Attributes.aspx) is some information on attributes in Asp.Net Mvc 2 (this is still applicable to Mvc3).  You should also do a search on Data Annotations -- This is how you can do a lot of validation on your models.

Answer (score 1):

Look at all the 'attribute' ending list here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc(VS.100).aspx

Data annotation are listed here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901590(v=vs.95).aspx

FYI the ones above you mentioned have nothing to do with MVC, they are test project attributes  *only*

Answer (score 1):

Attributes are used to embed additional metadata information about types, members and assemblies. Many CLR functionalities like serialization, security etc are implemented via attributes. We can define our own attributes and use them with class, members etc. The additional information is compiled into underlying assembly and can be retrieved at runtime via reflection.

For more on attributes, check out : [Attributes in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/attributes.aspx)

Comment: That was a great description of attributes! A lot of people don't realize they're metadata and are only accessible through reflection.